# Get childitems of SVG tag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, svg

How do i retrieve elements under svg class.I have tried all options like find element by tag or id.It doesnt work 
HTML page like this . I need to click on the title element given within the path style

```
<div id="pie4" class="left-top sp-workareaitem-content sap-chart" data-color="blue" data-charttype="pie" data-dimension="CATEGORY" data-title="CATEGORY-PIE" data-sap-widget="chart" style="display: block;">
<svg class="sap-piechart" width="82" height="82">
<g>
<path style="pointer-events: all;" transform="translate(41, 41)" fill="rgb(120,160,200)" title="Others : 13" d="M2.38499964133947e-15,-38.949999999999996A38.949999999999996,38.949999999999996 0 0,1 37.793018538450056,9.422857833607061L19.89106238865793,4.959398859793191A20.5,20.5 0 0,0 1.255262969126037e-15,-20.5Z">
<path style="pointer-events: all;" transform="translate(41, 41)" fill="rgb(81,122,162)" title="Notebooks : 10" d="M37.793018538450056,9.422857833607061A38.949999999999996,38.949999999999996 0 0,1 -2.717014652333681,38.85511975762015L-1.4300077117545693,20.450063030326397A20.5,20.5 0 0,0 19.89106238865793,4.959398859793191Z">
```

Kindly help me

Comment: Presumably you want to do this using JavaScript or with a Javascript-based library such as JQuery. Standard XML DOM methods/utilities and libraries would apply to SVG like any other XML language. There is nothing specific about SVG that would prevent you using standard tools.

Comment: Hi . I am uisng Selenium with Python ,and i dnt think there is anything specific methods for DOM in python bindings .If naything please let me know .
I am beginner in Selenium

Comment: Yes there are "specific methods for DOM in Python bindings" - See here: "The Document Object Model API" http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html This should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

My comments as an answer:

- Standard XML DOM methods/utilities and libraries would apply to SVG
  like any other XML language. There is nothing specific about SVG that
  would prevent you using standard tools.
- See here: "The Document Object Model API"
  docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html This should have everything you
  need
- ...particularly here:
  http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.childNodes

I've added Python and Selenium as tags to your question now that you have been more specific about the language and libraries that you are trying to apply. With these tags this will help others find your question and contribute answers as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for addind the tags . I shall look into the docs and come back to you if any queries .

Comment: @user1117498 - +1 you're welcome, and would you like to accept my answer? :) (If you would like to accept the answer, just click the check/tick by to left of it to make it become solid green, thanks)

Comment: Hi , I gave a try to the above described suggestion.The document says to use node.childnodes .can I use for element .Fir instance ,i find a element :elem = self.browser.find_element_by_id("pie4") x = elem.childNodes print x I think this is not allowed . It gives error 'Web element'object has no attribute 'childNodes'.

Comment: I have also tried using self.dom.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].firstChild.data.This given error .dom is not imported....Please let me know how do i write syntax to get the node and its child nodes